# WEBサーバーが返すディレクトリリストのタイムスタンプをJSTにしたい

Tags: untagged

Debian(Strech)上でLighttpdをWEBサーバーにしています。
WEBクライアントからサーバーにアクセスし、ディレクトリリストを取得するとファイルのタイムスタンプがUTCで返されます。JSTで返すように変更したいのですが、何を設定したらよいのでしょうか。

他のDebianマシンで同じようにLighttpdを立ち上げましたが、こちらは最初からJSTで返されます。二つのサーバーで設定の違いを探したのですが見つからず困り果てています。

Answer (score 1):

起動時にtimezoneがUTCになっていたのが原因でした。